# When does operating system's virtual page address translation happen?

Tags: memory, operating-system

I'm reading "Operating System Principles and Practices".

It says that there are hardware virtual pages on top of hardware physical pages. And there is also operating system's virtual pages on top of hardware virtual pages, mapping os virual pages to hardware virtual pages.

So, my question is - if address translation happens when processor accesses memory address, how can processor know about os page mapping to be able to translate addresses correctly?

Comment: Perhaps you should move this question to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system has to maintain page tables that defines the mapping from logical pages to physical page frames. The location of the page tables is defined using system registers.